# Correct handling of NSJSONSerialization (try catch) in Swift (2.0)?

Tags: ios, swift

arowmy init works fine in Swift < 2 but in Swift 2 I get a error message from Xcode `Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled` at `let anyObj = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject]`. I think in my case I can´t use a try catch block because super is not initialized at this time.  "Try" need a function that throws.

here is my function:

```
required init(coder aDecoder : NSCoder)
{
    self.name  = String(stringInterpolationSegment: aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String!)
    self.number = Int(aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("number"))
    self.img = String(stringInterpolationSegment: aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("image") as! String!)
    self.fieldproperties = []

    var tmpArray = [String]()
    tmpArray = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("properties") as! [String]


    let c : Int = tmpArray.count
    for var i = 0; i < c; i++
    {
        let data : NSData = tmpArray[i].dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

         // Xcode(7) give me error: 'CAll can thorw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled'
        let anyObj =  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject]

        let label = anyObj["label"] as AnyObject! as! String
        let value = anyObj["value"] as AnyObject! as! Int
        let uprate = anyObj["uprate"] as AnyObject! as! Int
        let sufix = anyObj["sufix"] as AnyObject! as! String

        let props = Fieldpropertie(label: label, value: value, uprate: uprate, sufix: sufix)
        self.fieldproperties.append(props)
    }
}
```

Xcode mean that:
`let anyObj = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject]`

but I have no idea to do here the right think according to this document https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

Comment: Please read full articles, not just the part that you think is important. You already have a "function that throws" - `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData`.

Comment: @Rob yes i mean Swift 2.0.

Comment: Voted down because example code is not a useful reference to previous methods and examples.

Comment: @NathanMcKasklei have no idea what you mean. the code describes my question.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The `jsonObject` can `throw` errors, so put it within `do` block, use `try`, and `catch` any errors thrown. In Swift 3:

```
do {
    let anyObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String: Any]

    let label = anyObj["label"] as! String
    let value = anyObj["value"] as! Int
    let uprate = anyObj["uprate"] as! Int
    let sufix = anyObj["sufix"] as! String

    let props = Fieldpropertie(label: label, value: value, uprate: uprate, sufix: sufix)

    // etc.
} catch {
    print("json error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Or, in Swift 4, you can simplify your code by making your `struct` conform to `Codable`:

```
struct Fieldpropertie: Codable {
    let label: String
    let value: Int
    let uprate: Int
    let suffix: String
}
```

Then

```
do {
    let props = try JSONDecoder().decode(Fieldpropertie.self, from: data)
    // use props here; no manual parsing the properties is needed
} catch {
    print("json error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

For Swift 2, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31296955/5).

Comment: Oh thanks. It work´s fine. I do not know why I have not done it ;)

Comment: @SaumilShah, see edit:
    catch let error1 as NSError{
        print("json error: \(error1.localizedDescription)")
    }

Comment: I tried it but Xcode says create throw....Could you please share any example with handle with throw?

Comment: @SaumilShah - We can show you how to throw, but it's probably better to just refer to [_The Swift Programming Languages: Error Handling_](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508). Or create your own question with a [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of the error you are receiving.

Comment: Thank you so much for support

Comment: I meant the do try catch part

Comment: @Rocotilos - This use of `do`-`try`-`catch` to catch a `NSError` is unique to Swift. In Objective-C, it doesn't throw errors. It throws exceptions, which, despite using confusingly similar syntax, is a completely different thing. You generally shouldn't write Objective-C code that catches exceptions, but rather you should eliminate them during the development process. I'd suggest you post your own question showing us what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

JSONSerialization.JSONObject throws ErrorType and not NSError.

so the correct catch is

```
do {
    let anyObj = try JSONSerialization.JSONObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
    // use anyObj here
} catch let error {
    print("json error: \(error)")
}
```

The type of `error` in `catch let error` is `ErrorType`

Comment: According to the documentation JSONObjectWithData throws an NSError, which conforms to ErrorType.

Comment: Yes, this is what the text says. The coded contract says ErrorType. When you do this inside closures and do not respect the coded contract, you'll get errors that are really hard to understand. When you catch only NSError, the compiler has to assume that there are uncatched cases left which can lead into trouble in context.

Comment: localizedDescription is not defined for ErrorType. And I have a warning on the line `let error as ErrorType` saying that the test is always true.

Comment: You are correct, `ErrorType` is redundant in `let error as ErrorType` and it has no localizedDescription. and it has no localizedDescription. I will fix my answer here.

Answer (score -3):

Don't know if it'll solve your problem, but isn't the method `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`? I think you're missing the `error` parameter.

Comment: No, in Swift 2.0, where you have the new `try`-`catch` mechanism, the `JSONObjectWithData` now doesn't use the `error` parameter, but rather throws the error instead.

Comment: @Rob Ahh, I see. The question said Swift 1.2, which is what I'm using, so I thought this might be the problem.