# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value jsonResult

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

it always tell me error,but I don't know what that is error.I have use the method before, but now it is error

```
                let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! Array<AnyObject>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct handling of NSJSONSerialization (try catch) in Swift (2.0)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296545/correct-handling-of-nsjsonserialization-try-catch-in-swift-2-0)

Comment: A more complete code sample would be of use to us.