# Conflict between MapKit in Swift 2 / Xcode 7.2 and Swift 1.2 / Xcode 6.3

Tags: swift, swift2, mapkit, xcode7

I'm using a tutorial for MapKit http://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial

It is taught using Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.3.  In my Project, however, I am getting some errors. The code below is directly from the tutorial at

I've broken out the relevant lines in the code below labeled as (A) and (B).  The respective errors are as follows:

(A) **`Missing argument label 'rawValue.' in call** - Adding the rawValue argument label does not help

(B) **Extra argument 'error' in call** - 
Removing the 'error' argument does not help

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    var artworks = [Artwork]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 21.282778, longitude: -157.829444)
        centerLocationOnMap(initialLocation)

        mapView.delegate = self

        // show artwork on map
        let artwork = Artwork(title: "King David Kalakaua",
            locationName: "Waikiki Gateway Park",
            discipline: "Sculpture",
            coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 21.283921, longitude: -157.831661)
        )

        mapView.addAnnotation(artwork)

    }

    let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000;
    func centerLocationOnMap(location: CLLocation) {
        let regionCoordinates = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
        mapView.setRegion(regionCoordinates, animated: true)
    }


func loadInitialData() {

  let fileName = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PublicArt", ofType: "json");
  var readError : NSError?
```

(A)

```
  var data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: fileName!, options: NSDataReadingOptions(0), error: &readError)!
  var error: NSError?
```

(B)

```
let jsonObject: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, 
    options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: &error)
```

.

```
  if let jsonObject = jsonObject as? [String: AnyObject] where error == nil,
  let jsonData = JSONValue.fromObject(jsonObject)?["data"]?.array {
    for artworkJSON in jsonData {
      if let artworkJSON = artworkJSON.array,
      // 5
      artwork = Artwork.fromJSON(artworkJSON) {
        artworks.append(artwork)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods signature change in swift 2
You can look at NSData and NSJSONSerialization apple documentations

You must remove the errors parameters and use try before calling the functions

And for options you can put [] -> no options

```
try NSData(contentsOfFile: fileName!, options: [])

try NSJSONSerialization.
```

see [Correct handling of NSJSONSerialization (try catch) in Swift (2.0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296545/correct-handling-of-nsjsonserialization-try-catch-in-swift-2-0)

And you must to catch the errors with a do { code } catch {  }, or just for test purpose use try!