# Extra argument error in call

Tags: swift2

I have been trying to login for a while using php but I have a final bug that stops me from finishing. It turns out to give a bug in NSJSONSerialization where the error tells me: error extra argument in call. Then I will provide a screenshot so that the error is clearer and the code so you can help me since I am in a blocking moment and I do not know how to solve it. Thanks in advance

Photo error: [
Code:

```
@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;



    if(userEmail!.isEmpty || userPassword!.isEmpty) { return; }

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/billapp/userSignIn.php");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "userEmail=\(userEmail)&userPassword=\(userPassword)";

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil{
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        var err: NSError?

        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error:NSError) as? NSDictionary

        if let parseJSON = json {
            var resultValue:String = parseJSON["status"] as String!;
            print("result: \(resultValue)")

            if(resultValue=="Success")
            {
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();

                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

[last error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJXYe.png)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization/1415493-jsonobject - drop the `NS`, change the method name, remove the `error`, wrap it in a `try`.

Comment: Can you adapt it with my code please?

Comment: If it works, but in the line of if let parseJSON = json I have an error that says: use of unresolved identifier 'json'

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the quick fix sugestions. Doing so will let you end up like this:

```
do {
    var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(), options: .mutableContainers)
     if let parseJSON = json {
          //your code
     }
} catch {
    //handle error
}
```

Comment: I cant use this because I'm on swift 2 and your code is 3

Comment: Then why is the question tagged Swift 3 @stackamr ???

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a mistake. But could you help me to do it with swift 2?

Comment: Swift2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296545/correct-handling-of-nsjsonserialization-try-catch-in-swift-2-0

Comment: If it works, but in the line of if let parseJSON = json I have an error that says: use of unresolved identifier 'json'

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Objective C, as per the new methodolgy in Swift, errors are handled using try/catch block instead of passing the error object in the method.

Use the following code for Swift 3.

```
 do {
      var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) 
        if let parseJSON = json {
        var resultValue:String = parseJSON["status"] as String!;
        print("result: \(resultValue)")

        if(resultValue=="Success")
        {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
        }
    }
 } catch let error {
        //Perform the error handling here
 }
```

Following for Swift 2

```
do {
      var json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers)
        if let parseJSON = json {
        var resultValue:String = parseJSON["status"] as String!;
        print("result: \(resultValue)")

        if(resultValue=="Success")
        {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
        }
    }
 } catch let error {
        //Perform the error handling here
 }
```

Comment: this is swift 2

Comment: I have edited the answer to incorporate for Swift 2 as well.

Comment: If it works, but in the line of if let parseJSON = json I have an error that says: use of unresolved identifier 'json'

Comment: I think you are doing the work out of the `do` block. Write the code below the `var json = ...` line and you wouldn't get this error.

Comment: i edit my post, last line I post a photo with error, please help me

Comment: click on " last error"

Comment: I made the edits in ans, check it now.

Comment: the same error: initializer for conditional binding must have optional type not anyObject

Comment: I cant understand why not work

Comment: download my project and fix it. http://www86.zippyshare.com/v/iP9iQuXX/file.html